# Can you prevent short-circuit evaluation in Lua?

Tags: lua, user-input, conditional-statements, short-circuiting

I am working on a script that allows user entry of Lua (specifically, boolean conditionals), and I am trying to provide a feature that will perform a quick error check for the script that is entered.

It's easy enough to throw an error if `loadstring()` fails, so syntax issues are readily handled.

However, if variables are improperly entered, it is harder to detect a problem.

Let's say the user enters the following:

```
value.custom_value_1 == 1 and valse.custom_value_2 ~= 1
```

As far as the syntax goes, `loadstring()` is quite satisfied -- it adds 'return ' as a prefix to that string.

My next step is to check for errors when we execute what was entered by the user.  The problem is, when `value.custom_value_1 ~= 1`, the logic will short-circuit since we're dealing with `and` - there's no point in going further, we already have false on the left-hand side.

What I would like is to find a way to cause Lua to completely evaluate the expression, rather than short-circuiting.  If it did so, the spelling error `valse` would be caught (regardless of `value.custom_value_1`'s value) and I can provide an error message to the end user.

Any thoughts?

My current best idea is to filter through the user input, sorting out every value entered (basically, whatever's not an a conditional `or`, `and`, ...) and just doing it manually.  But I thought it's worth checking to see if there's a better way.

Comment: Is modifying Lua source an option?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind parsing the string up-front you could use a library like https://github.com/stravant/LuaMinify/blob/master/ParseLua.lua to parse the source into an AST, modify the short-circuiting notes into function calls like

```
function my_and(x, y)
    return x and y
end
```

Then you compile this AST to check for the errors.

Seems a lot hassle though just to catch trivial errors.

Comment: I definitely agree on the part about hassle.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Preventing short-circuit evaluation is not something you would want to / could do. That's just the way it works.

What you could do instead is something like:

```
if(logic1 and logic2)
{
// code on success
}
else
// check what kind of error we have
{
   if(~logic1)
   {
      // throw error type 1
   }
   if(~logic2)
   {
      // throw error type 2
   }
}
```

Comment: Because this is user-entered, and some conditions may be checked extremely rarely, I definitely want to evaluate all of the values entered by the user as a one time thing.  I don't want to turn off short-circuit eval for everything, always.  I just want to check to make sure everything they're checking is actually available, spelled correctly, etc.  Short-circuit evaluation is currently a barrier, unless I do some elaborate string parsing to break down every possible nested condition.

Comment: or just write a test function, which checks everything...
bool test(){logic1, logic2 ...}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if anyone's answer was accurate, but the literal question was 'can you prevent short-circuit evals' and I was not able to find a way to do that.

I ultimately chopped up the user input and tested each component individually, gathering those errors and feeding them back to the user.  Seems okay for now.